# Django url, admin path doesn't have /admin/ in it

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls, namecheap

Django==2.1
Python 3.5.7
I'm trying to save admin form and the url is **/admin/landing/banner/add/** but in debug it says that it is **landing/banner/add/**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://********.****/admin/landing/banner/add/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view

Using the URLconf defined in mainapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
contact/
demo/
success/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
admin/
```

The current path, **landing/banner/add/**, didn't match any of these.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('landing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

landing urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', include('contact.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
]
```

contact urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import ContactView, SuccessView, DemoView
urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', ContactView.as_view()),
    path('demo/', DemoView.as_view()),
    path('success/', SuccessView.as_view()),
]
```

Banner model, I didn't add a get_absolute_url method, should I?

```
class SingleActiveModel(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.active:
            allActive = type(self).objects.filter(active=True)
            if self.pk:
                allActive = allActive.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            allActive.update(active=False)
        super(SingleActiveModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Banner(SingleActiveModel):
    banner_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    banner_text = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    button_text = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    button_link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    second_button_text = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    second_button_link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.banner_text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.banner_title

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.active

class BannerModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ImagesInline, ]
    list_display = ['banner_title', "__unicode__", 'active', "timestamp"]
    list_filter = ['active', 'timestamp']
    search_fields = ['banner_title', 'banner_text']
    class Meta:
        model = Banner

admin.site.register(Banner, BannerModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Updated question with Banner model, but I don't have get_absolute_url metrhod. What is it? can you please show me?

Comment: As an aside, `__unicode__` is from Python 2, it won't have any effect in Python 3.

Comment: Updated with BannerModelAdmin and SingleActiveModel